# How do I write logs to cloudwatch using aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

i'm trying to write a log to cloudwatch (just to understand how it works)

so from the aws-cli (already configured) i'm issuing this command

`aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name testgroup --log-stream-name teststream1 --log-events timestamp=1587488538,message=hello`

on cloudwatch the group-name and the stream-log already exist and the the names are correct

the output of the command is the following

`{ "rejectedLogEventsInfo": { "tooOldLogEventEndIndex": 1 } }`

the user i'm using has the "AdministratorAccess" policy attached (and to be sure i've added "CloudWatchFullAccess" policy as well)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert your timestamp to milliseconds version (multiply with 1000 in your case)

```
aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name testgroup --log-stream-name teststream1 --log-events timestamp=1587488538000,message=hello
```

please check [AWS CLI examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-log-events.html)